# How I can debug my IONIC android application with a android device connected using USB debugging option?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have developed a app which can read a bar code and receive some data and acts upon the data. As I am using desktop there have no camera and I can,t   being able to check the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily debug your Android Application using [Chrome Remote Debugging for Android Devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/). so you will be able to:

- Set up your Android device for remote debugging, and discover it from your development machine;
- Inspect and debug live content on your Android device from your
  development machine;
- Screencast content from your Android device onto a DevTools instance
  on your development machine

Hope I help!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just set up your Android device for remote dubugging and go on

> chrome://inspect/#devices

I hope that answers your question.